# No such directory: failed to create my first app in rails

Tags: software-installation, ruby

I have tried installing the gem bundler, and all related sorts, but this can't go. Is it because i want to create my new app in the home directory? Is it a must that it should be created in the system root here the Ruby and rails was installed?
This is what it brings;

```
run  bundle install --local
/usr/bin/ruby2.3: No such file or directory -- /usr/bin/bundle (LoadError)
         run  bundle exec spring binstub --all
/usr/bin/ruby2.3: No such file or directory -- /usr/bin/bundle (LoadError)
```

Comment: No it should in the `/home` directory must be some config issue. Looks like ruby can't see the bundler you installed

Comment: how do i edit my config settings to match the default ruby files?

Comment: It's how you installed the bundler that matters as regards the way you setup ruby on your system

Comment: Check this example here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-with-rbenv-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: This worked for me perfectly